# How do I `avconv` every m4a in a dir to mp3s?

Tags: files, mp3, avconv

So I'm trying to convert lots of m4as to mp3s, and I think the best way to do that is using `avconv`.

The problem is, I can't seem to find any solid examples on how to use `avconv`.

Looking at the man page, it has a ridiculous amount of flags/options, and I can't make sense of it.

How can I batch convert with `avconv`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To do a single file:

```
$ avconv -i m.m4a m.mp3
```

To do a batch you could wrap this in a for loop:

```
$ for i in *.m4a; do
    avconv -i "$i" "${i/.m4a/.mp3}"
done
```

This will take all the files that are present in the current directory with the extension `.m4a` and run each of them through `avconv`. The 2nd argument, `${i/.m4a/.mp3}` does a substitution on the contents of the variable `$i`, swapping out `.m4a` for `.mp3`.

**NOTE:** As a one liner:

```
$ for i in *.m4a; do avconv -i "$i" "${i/.m4a/.mp3}"; done
```

Comment: How could I consolidate that loop onto one line? Or would it be easier to just put it in a shell script?

Comment: @evamvid - see update.

Comment: I ended up putting it in a shell script last night, but thanks!

Comment: @evamvid - OK. If your issues been resolved can you please mark this A as accepted so other passerby's know that your issue's been resolved.

Comment: yeah, just did.